# Android Studio: building trying to find version not stated in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use an old version of appcompat-v7. My build.gradle has the following lines:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

The full build.gradle is below:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

final def extension = android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example."
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
extension

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

However, when running it gives me the error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            [removed links]
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            WaitroseStock:app:unspecified
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar
>        Required by:
>            WaitroseStock:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0 > com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0

This is because I have deleted version 23 so it doesn't confuse itself with that newer version and cause errors. Why is it still looking for v23 when I have requested v21?

Comment: Did you change buildToolsVersion, in build.gradle ?

Comment: I believe I have. Edited comment with the full build.gradle.

Comment: Right click on your module, Open Module Settings, Properties and Dependencies are set to v21 or v23 ?

Comment: Dependencies is set to v21.

Properties was empty. I have changed Compile Sdk Version to API 21, build tools version to 21.1.2. Same error

I have also deleted all build-tools that aren't 21.1.2 from the SDK Manager and double-checked the location on my hard disk.

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync`

Comment: Hum ok, and when graddle ask you to sync your project you have no error ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya When I clean it displays the same message.

Comment: When syncing it shows:

`Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:/WaitroseStock/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>`

Comment: Can you re install in your sdk the version 23, and put your project in v23. Check if it works.
If Yes, change the version again, then delete version 23.

Comment: As this `file:/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.0/appcompat-v7-23.0.0.aar Required by: WaitroseStock:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` says, play-services-8.4.0 requires the appcompat-v7/23.0.0 version. So try changing the play service version to lower one or try replacing `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` with `compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
applicationId "your package name"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Restart your android studio and rebuild the project.
Hope this will help you...

Comment: Change your applicationId in this build file from applicationId "com.example." to applicationId " your package name in Android manifest file".... According to Android Docs....the applicationId attribute is used to uniquely identify application packages for publishing. ...then sync and rebuild the project